# How to iterate over a class having an array with the keys in a specific order

Tags: php

I have three Classes: Table, Row, and Cell.

Table has an array of Rows and an array with order of columns.

Row has an array of Cells and Cell has textValue.

Both Table and Row implements IteratorAggregate.

My problem is that Table has an order of columns specify by the user, but when the program iterate on rows, it returns the cells in the order they were added. 
I tried to implement Iterator instead of IteratorAggregate but I do not know how to pass the array that table has with order of column.

I want to keep the iteration as simple as possible, with this I meant that I want to be able to foreach the Table and Row.

```
<?php


class Table implements \IteratorAggregate
{

    private $order;
    private $rows;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rows = [];
        $this->order = [];
    }

    public function addRow(Row $row){
        array_push($this->rows, $row);
    }

    public function setOrder(Array $order){
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new \ArrayIterator($this->rows);
    }
}

class Row implements \IteratorAggregate 
{
    private $cells;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cells = [];
    }

    public function addCell(Cell $cell){
        array_push($this->cells, $cell);
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new \ArrayIterator($this->cells);
    }
}

class Cell extends Model{

    public $text;

    public function __construct($text = "")
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }
}
```

An example would be having a row with cells = [a,b,c]. Iterator always will give a,b,c. But the order could be specify in the table class and print something like b,c,a or c,a,b.

Comment: If data are in database, I will do sorting on db level

Comment: the problem is that the order is added in runtime by the user and it cannot be solve just ordering asc or desc

Comment: Added code and example @Yoshi.

Comment: The main problem is that table has the order and row does not know the order.

Comment: I'd add a method `setOrder` on `Row`, too. When the order is set on the `Table` you set it on the rows as well. Or you could set it in the `Table.getIterator` method.

Comment: Then you'd need a custom iterator for `Row` that takes the order into account.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan, when u say setOrder something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2175400/5335897 ?

Btw Implemented this and it works but I am worry about having to go row by row to update them.

Comment: @RemoFiorentino an approach would be to have a custom `Table` iterator, that sets the order on the `Row` lazily just before emitting it. So, unless a `Row` is produced, its order won't be changed.

Comment: @RemoFiorentino and by `setOrder` I meant the same method as that on `Table`. I was not referring to the algorithm to sort a row based on the order array, as I thought you have a design problem, not an algorithm problem.