# How to change a position of an multidimensional array in a multidimensional array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have something like this:

```
$C = [ 
$B = [ $S = [$D[]], $H = [$C[]], $G = [$L[]]]]
```

I need to put array $H (which I know the name), with all of it's elements on the first place, so it goes like this:

```
$C = [ 
$B = [ $H = [$C[]], $S = [$D[]], $G = [$L[]]]]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change orders of array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175350/how-to-change-orders-of-array)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but no. It is not the same.

Comment: Could you please reformat the arrays, it's hard to visualise them all in one line.

Comment: I have reformated it, hopefully it's more understandable.

Comment: It's hard to understand, can you please confirm is it like 
$C = [ 'B' => [ 'S' => ['C' => []], 'H'=> ['D' => []], 'G' => ['L' => []]]];

Comment: Yes, it's exactly like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this solution solves your purpose:

```
<?php

$C = ['B' => ['S' => ['C' => []], 'H' => ['D' => []], 'G' => ['L' => []]]];

function moveArrayElementOnTop($array, $element = 'H')
{
    $finalArray = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == $element) {
                $temp[$key][$k] = $v;
                unset($array[$key][$k]);
            }
        }

        if (isset($temp[$key])) {
            $finalArray[$key] = $temp[$key] + $array[$key];
        } else {
            $finalArray[$key] = $array[$key];
        }

    }

    return $finalArray;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(moveArrayElementOnTop($C));
echo "</pre>";
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/AVQBH